GitHub actions Docker build and push image context problem
I try to use Github Actions to build dev container from VScode in Windows 11.
My folder and file in Git repository:

My test repo: https://github.com/blademoon/DOCKER_image_build_and_push
My Github Action:
name: Публикация образа на Docker Hub

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    paths:
      - .devcontainer/**

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push devcontainer Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      contents: read
      attestations: write
      id-token: write
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@9ec57ed1fcdbf14dcef7dfbe97b2010124a938b7
        with:
          images: artyomboyko/github_image
          tags: latest

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          context: ./.devcontainer
          file: Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}


I am trying to run a Dockerfile build from the .devcontainer folder. But the build crashes with an error: Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open Dockerfile: no such file or directory
My questions:

How to write correctly this section from docker-image.yml:

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          context: ./.devcontainer
          file: Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}


Why is specifying the Dockerfile path as follows:

...
context: ./.devcontainer
file: Dockerfile
...

is incorrect?
